# How do I know login and password of my virtual machine

Tags: virtualbox, login, password

I use a virtual machine called 'RelaxEd' on VirtualBox (Ubuntu 16.04 amd64). After starting it I will be able to access `localhost:3000` and then load the web pages. For some reasons I copied its files from `Virtualbox VMs` folder to another computer (still Ubuntu 16.04 amd64) in order to use it on that second computer. But when I start the virtual machine I'm asked login and password which I don't know. However,it isn't required in my first computer ( I guess login and password were saved). I also created  a snapshot of the VM in the first computer and copied it to the second PC thinking I would be able to use without login and password. But I can't start the VM on the second computer by that snapshot either (after loading 90% an error is appearing). 
How can I get the login and password of the VM to use it on the second computer? [image: RelaxEd on my second pc]

Comment: You can't get the password out, you can only reset it.

Comment: @HellionWisp what about login?

Comment: You can't login without the password I guess. Can you reset the password on the working VM? At least then you will know what the password is.

Comment: @HellionWisp I don't know resetting

Comment: Best to reset the password. You could try some of the tools to discover the password such as john the ripper on your first machine . John will find weak passwords.

Comment: The  usual way of resetting a root password is by mounting the root volume from within a system you do know the root password for, such as a live CD, and following a process. If you can find a way to mount the VM image in another a Linux install I'll provide you an answer to reset your passwords.

Comment: @HellionWisp - No need for anything like that, boot to recovery mode - https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password

Comment: @HellionWisp in order to reset the password by 'passwd', the username is required. is there any way to find it?

Comment: @Steve either `ls /home` or `grep 1000 /etc/passwd` , assuming you have only one user .